# generic class for CRUD operations in asp.net Using C#

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner at Asp.net using C# and worked mostly in web forms, most of the time when i do tasks, i repeat the same code over and over at different classes, for example, for inserting data, i have to right insert functionality for every specific form. What i want is to have a generic class where these methods for Insertion, deletion, selection, and updation are defined generically and i only have to instantiate these objects where i submit forms and pass data through parameters to these objects. In Php, we called it a dbClass, i dont know what its called in asp.net, its basically a single class being utilized at every crud operation taking place in the application. It would be highly appreciated if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you using an ORM like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) and the ([Generic](http://2guysfrommumbai.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/entity-framework-generic-repository-pattern-part-1/)) [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). I believe that will suit your needs and will help you enforce the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

In addition, if you're using ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5 you should take a look at the new [Model Binding](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/whats-new#_Toc318097387) feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Meryovi. I followed yours steps and am quite happy learning and implementing EF now, its a piece of cake! Way to easy for CRUD operations! Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Steps
{
    public class conn
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public conn()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LCCSERVER;Initial Catalog=steps;User ID=sa;Password=admin123";
            cmd.Connection = con;
        }

        public void openconnection()
        //using for eliminating the connection error
        {

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
        }

        public SqlCommand getcommand
        {
            get
            {
                return cmd;
            }
        }
    }



    public static class crud
    {
        static conn c = new conn();
        public static string insupdel(string spname, params Object[] values)

        {
            c.openconnection();
            c.getcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            c.getcommand.CommandText = spname;
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(c.getcommand);
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            foreach (SqlParameter spram in c.getcommand.Parameters)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    spram.Value = values[i];
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
            }
            c.getcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "success";
        }

        public static DataSet getdata(string spname, params Object[] values)

        {
            c.openconnection();
            c.getcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            c.getcommand.CommandText = spname;
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(c.getcommand);
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            foreach (SqlParameter spram in c.getcommand.Parameters)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    spram.Value = values[i];
                    i++;
                }
                j++;
            }

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.SelectCommand = c.getcommand;
            ad.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```